# Print particular key value based on the user input from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to print "account number" and "account balance" from list of dictionaries database. First I have verified the user inputs like FirstName,LastName and date of birth  from the database, but now I don't know how to print its other values by filtering the dictionary in list based on the user input. Here is my code:

```
 import re
    import datetime
    from datetime import date
    from collections import defaultdict
    from operator import itemgetter
    userDetails=[]


    accountDetails = [
                        {"FirstName": "JOHN", "LastName": "DENIS","date of Birth": "01-06-1992", "Account Number": "432524352345234", "Account Balance": "50000"},
                        {"FirstName": "AKASH", "LastName": "MAHAJAN", "date of Birth": "04-02-1995","Account Number": "43252435242342", "Account Balance": "100000"},
                        {"FirstName": "AMAN", "LastName": "RANA","date of Birth": "11-04-1996", "Account Number": "432524324234424", "Account Balance": "60000"},]
                        ]

  firstName=str(input("Enter First Name").upper())

    def isDuplicate(value, fieldName, database):
                        for entry in database:

                          if fieldName in entry and entry[fieldName] == value:

                                return True
                        else:
                                return False
     while True:  

           if(isDuplicate(firstName, "FirstName", accountDetails))==True:

                            userDetails.append(firstName)
                            break

                      else:
                            print('Enter valid First Name')
                            firstName=str(input("Enter First Name").upper())


    lastName=str(input("Enter Last Name").upper())
    #LASTNAME=firstName.upper()
    isDuplicate(lastName, "LastName", accountDetails)
    while True:  

           if(isDuplicate(lastName, "LastName", accountDetails))==True:
                            print("entered correct lastname")
                            userDetails.append(lastName)
                            break


           else:
                            print('Enter valid last Name')
                            lastName=str(input("Enter last Name"))

    dateOfBirth=str(input("Enter date of birth"))
    while True:  

           if(isDuplicate(dateOfBirth, "date of Birth", accountDetails))==True:
                            print("entered correct date of birth")
                            userDetails.append(lastName)

                            break

                      else:
                            print('Enter valid date of birth')
                            dateOfBirth=str(input("Enter date of birth"))
    def printRequiredUserInfo(FirstName,AccountNumer,Accountbalance,Database):
            for entry in Database:

                if entry.get("FirstName")=FirstName:

                      print("Your Account number is "+ entry[AccountNumer])
                      print("Your Account balance is "+ entry[Accountbalance])
    printRequiredUserInfo(firstName,"Account Number","Account Balance",accountDetails)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in accountDetails:
    if (x["FirstName"]==firstName) and (x["LastName"]==lastName) and (x["date of Birth"]==dateOfBirth):
        print(x["Account Number"]," ",x["Account Balance"])
```

Comment: Consider adding some more content to your answer to explain why your solution works. This way, it will help future visitors to the site!